# When should I move from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-7

Some concerns:

- Drupal 6 doesn't work with php 5.3
- Drupal 7 doesn't have all the modules that Drupal 6 has
- I am very comfortable with Drupal 7 (I.e. I might have to learn quite a bit about Drupal 7 before being as comfortable with it as I am with Drupal 6)

So, based on these, when should I suck it up and make the move over to Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many considerations to make:

- Are you talking about your small, personal website, or a big platform with thousands of users and you are responsible for the contents?
- Did your server upgrade to PHP 5.3 all of a sudden?
- Does your server allow you to downgrade PHP from 5.3 to 5.2?
- Are you currently using a module that has not been ported to drupal 7?
- Are you eagerly expecting to use a specific feature of drupal 7?
- Do you feel uncomfortable using unstable modules (alpha, dev)?

Based on what you say, I don't think there's an answer, actually, unless you give some more context. In any case, you can do it when you feel up to it, just take the time to do the corresponding backups and try to read all the guides available so you won't mess up your current content. Good luck!